# Grid wrap in ListView item

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, grid, uwp

I have a very beautiful `Grid` control with a `WebView` in it and I am trying for more than 2 hours to wrap it in a `ListViewItem`.
This is my grid:

```
<Grid Width="450" Margin="0,-270,0,-200" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <WebView x:Name="Browser" Source="http://someurl.com" Margin="0,0,0,-150/>
</Grid>
```

and I am very happy with it's design.

When I try to wrap it in a `ListViewItem` the margins change a lot and I cant seem to find the correct one to make it look exactly the way the old `Grid` used to.
This is my `ListView`:

```
ListView x:Name="MyList1" BorderThickness="0" Width="500">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Width="450" Margin="0,-270,0,-200" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <WebView x:Name="Browser" Source="http://someurl.com" Margin="0,0,0,-150/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

The margins are hiding some part of the `WebView`. Hence the reason I need exactly the same margin.
I am trying to wrap it to a `ListView` to be able to create multiple `Items`.

Comment: It seems when we remove the `Margin` of the `Grid` in `DateTemplate`, we can set the WbeView in the `ListView`.